# JS: How to automate going up "parentNode" as many times as needed

Tags: javascript, function, parent-node

Let's say I have a `div` that's called Z`.`Z`that is a sub-sub-sub... child of a`div`called`B`which is a child of a`div`called`A`.

All the block from `B` to `Z` are set to `display=none` (`A` is visible).

If I click on a anchor that links to the block `Z`, I want it to be displayed.

For that I need to set the display of block Z`block`, but also its parent's display* to block, and its parents and all the way up to block B....

I don't want to "hard" code all the possible level because I could have 2, 4 or 10 levels. So I would like to find a way to do it automatically.

I simplified a bit the example above as I have to set the `display=block` every 2 "generations" (cf in my code the `parentNode.parentNode`)

So far this is my code (with 2 level down the rabbit hole!) and not automation:

```
function indexLink(link_to_anchor) {
    var x = document.getElementById(link_to_anchor);
    if (x.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("class") == "divcodebox") {
        if (x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("class") == "divcodebox") {
            x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
        }
        x.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
    }
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```

---

Using indexLink() recursively :

```
function indexLink(link_to_anchor) {
    var x = document.getElementById(link_to_anchor);
    x.style.display = "block";
    if (x.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("class") == "divcodebox") {
        x.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
        indexLink(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just call `indexLink()` within itself with the parent of `link_to_anchor` (=x.parentNode) as long as its display is not block (or none depending on your scheme).

Comment: @Lain, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it (cf the edit at the bottom of my question), but I get this error ` Cannot read property 'style' of null`. Could you give me a code example please?

Comment: First, you have to pass an element and not its `id` unless you want to guarantee that all elements on your site have indeed an `id`. Therefore just pass a HTMLElement and change `x` to `var x = link_to_anchor`. Then you call `x.parentNode && indexLink(x.parentNode)` instead of `indexLink(x)`.

Comment: Ok I didn't get that! Thanks !

Comment: Made you a little example just so you can see how it would have looked like for learning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple `for` loop?

```
    var x = document.getElementById(link_to_anchor);
    for (parent = x.parentNode; parent; parent = parent.parentNode) {
      // do whatever
    }
```

You can of course keep a counter to check how many steps you've traversed, etc. The `.parentNode` reference from the `document` level will be `null`, so that ends the iteration. (You can break out of the loop early too.)

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, It's working but I don't understand the for condition. I try to related it to    `for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {` but I don't understand how the middle `parent` don't stop everything right at the first step. Unless this `parent` gets updated at each loop ?

Comment: @MagTun yes, it gets updated by the third clause in the loop header: `parent = parent.parentNode`.  The middle expression will be "truthy" unless `parent` is `null`, which it will be if the iteration makes it up to the `document` level.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show how your recursive function should look like based on your code and not a finished example.

```
;function indexLink(element){
    //REM: Change the parameter to the actual element instead of its id
    //var x = document.getElementById(link_to_anchor);

    //REM: Check if the element exists and the style does not equal block
    //REM: If the styles are set by class you need to change this to computed style
    if(element && element.style.display !== 'block'){
        //REM: Set the display to block
        element.style.display = 'block';

        //REM: Repeating the same logic for the parentNode
        indexLink(element.parentNode)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursiveApply(from, to, fn) {
    let current = from;

    while(current !== to) {
        fn(current);
        current = current.parentElement;
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
var a = document.getElementById("1");
var b = document.getElementById("2");

recursiveApply(a, b, function(element) {
    // do stuff with the element
    console.log(element)
});
```